# Difference between load word and move?

Tags: assembly, mips, nios

What is the difference between

`ldw r8,0(r4)`

and

`mov r8, r4`

Load word says "copy from memory" but when load word copies from r4, it is copying from register and not from memory right?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `lw` instruction (I assume that's what you meant since `ldw` isn't a standard MIPS instruction, though all the loads will be similar in the context of this answer) loads a word from the *memory address* specified by `0 + r4`, while `move`<sup>1</sup> simply transfers the value of `r4` into `r8`.

For example, let's say `r4` is currently `1234` and the word stored at `1234` in memory is `5678`.

The difference is thus:

```
move r8, r4            ; r8 is now 1234
lw   r8, 0(r4)         ; r8 is now 5678
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The `move` instruction" is actually a pseudo-instruction where `move $rt, $rs` is encoded as `addi $rt, $rs, 0`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer which was what I thought and why then is my r8 always 0 when it is supposed to be handling a call from a testing function? The background is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105322/how-to-proceed-coding-for-this-assignment and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152323/why-is-load-word-not-working

Comment: @Nick, looking over your other two questions, the initial value for `testmytime` _IS_ zero. It only seems to change on each test iteration using all that `randr` and other random stuff.